# The bibliography does not align during the submission to ArXiv

Tags: alignment, arxiv, bibliographystyle

During the submission of the latex-file (two-column style) to ArXiv I faced an unexpected problem with the alignment of the bibliography (see below the print screen attached), while this error is absent in my latex environment.

[image]

The problem is that the part of the bibliography moves to the neighboring column as one can see in the print screen.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,showpacs]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

text is here

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I appreciate for the help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. can you provide the code that causes your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the additional description has been added

Answer (score 1):

arXiv's `hyperref` configuration has `breaklinks=false`, so anything clickable will try and maintain single line fidelity. If you want this turned off add this line to your preamble:

```tex
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
```

Comment: This does work, thanks!